# mat-list does not appear inside mat-sidenav

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to make a side navigation bar with a menu consists of sections and sub suctions. the problem is that the mat-list looks like big transparent rectangle, and inspect telling that list is rendered correctly.
any help is appreciated.

```
<div fxLayout="column" >
        <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100%" >
              <app-header fxFlex="100%"> </app-header>
        </div>
        <mat-sidenav-container >
            <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" 
                         [fixedInViewport]="false" [fixedTopGap]="0"
                         [fixedBottomGap]="0">
                                <mat-list >
                                    <div *ngFor = "let section of defaultSections">
                                        <mat-list-item>{{section.name}}</mat-list-item>
                                            <mat-list>
                                                <div *ngFor="let subSection of section?.subSections">
                                                    <mat-list-item>
                                                        <!-- <mat-icon>{{subSection.icon}}</mat-icon> -->
                                                        <h4 mat-line>{{subSection.name}}</h4> 
                                                    </mat-list-item> 
                                                </div>
                                            </mat-list> 
                                    </div>
                                 </mat-list>
            </mat-sidenav>

            <mat-sidenav-content >

            </mat-sidenav-content>
        </mat-sidenav-container>
    </div>



<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[image]

**Update**
app.cpmponenet.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  defaultSections = [
        {id:1, name: 'Entries and Accounts', subSections: [
            {id:1, name: 'Journal Entries' , icon: 'book'},
            {id:2, name: 'charts of Accounts', icon: 'account_balance'},
        ]},
        {id:2, name: 'Financial Reports', subSections: [
            {id:1, name: 'General Ledure', icon: 'library_books'},
            {id:2, name: 'Income Statement', icon: 'event_notes'},
            {id:3, name: 'Balance Sheet', icon: 'event_notes'},
            {id:4, name: 'Cash Flow', icon: 'attach_money'}
        ]},
        {id:3, name: 'Bulletins and Currencies', subSections: [
            {id:1, name: 'Exchange Rate Bulletins', icon: 'format_list_bulleted'},
            {id:2, name: 'Currencies', icon: 'monetization_on'},
        ]}

        ];

}
```

Comment: Could you add your component's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working ok for me, I've quickly reproduced a similar example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xq2meb-zjyg1i) and I can see the list in my sidenav. Is there anything you are doing different that I have not taken into account in my example?

Comment: thanks for your efforts, I posted the component code, please take a look at it.

Comment: that's right, the code is fine, I'm using angular flex layout, I tried to use row layout and divide the side nav bar and content 30% by 70% but it didn't work as expected, when I used column layout it worked as expected but it doesn't make sense to me!, the result I got is conflicted with the angular flex Demo. could you please explain whats happening here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xq2meb-rjzqbt?file=app/sidenav-overview-example.html

Comment: For more explanation, please note that I used column layout, and gave 100% for both <mat-sidenav> and <mat-sidenav-content>, according to this demo https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs, the side nav bar and the content should appear above each other, but in this case they don't. I know that this exactly what I want, but I can't understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The code generated the list expectedly, but the text color was white (same as the background). Try setting a background, or changing the font color.

Comment: Strange enough, same happened with me. Color set to white for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed, the Angular Material theme Purple-Green (among others) sets mat-list-item color go white. When used on a page with white background, the text is hidden. Notice, page has the content

```
@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css
```

[image]